# Integrating embercli with existing non-ember application

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I have an existing application that doesn't use emberjs, and am looking at doing a re-write of the front end. I would like to incorporate emberjs into the project using embercli. While not a single page app the application only has 4 pages, each have allot going on, very heavy JS, so I thought it would make sense to make an emberjs app for each of the four pages, that way I could migrate page-by-page.

So the first page I was looking at migrating is the simplest of the four, a account page where account details/settings etc can be modified. This is what I've done:

Went into my js directory of my app (which has all the legacy code I intend to migrate) ran `ember new account` to create an embercli app in the account directory. After that I ran `ember build` to build my project, the compiled files were added to /account/dist . I then linked to the two JS files created in /account/dist/assets like so:

Now I see that embercli does create it's own index.html inside dist, but I will not be using that. I'm thinking I can just remove some of the stuff that I don't need before deployment.

My question is, does it seem like I am on the right path here? Is there any reason I shouldn't be trying to do what I am doing now? Are there more things I need to consider than just linking to the account.js and vendor.js scripts? I've done a fair bit of Googling but since these tools are still pretty new I didn't find much that was relevant to what I am trying to do.Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks much!

Comment: I would advise against creating an ember app for each page, especially if the purpose is to minimize payload or keep code minimalist. If the pages have a lot going on, then separate out the concerns using mixins, extends, components, and renders. I'm sure a lot of the non-ember code will be optimized using computed properties, bindings, etc, meaning you have less going on than you did before. Ember-cli doesn't support multiple apps as noted in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661924/multiple-apps-with-ember-cli). Have you used ember before?

Comment: @DuncanWalker - thanks for the reply. I have used ember for a small stand-alone project, didn't really get too far in depth though. I want to use Ember for the project I am re-factoring as ember-data seems perfect for use with the REST API driving my app. I want to use ember-cli as it is recommended to use a build system when you want to spread your views across multiple handlebar files, as I do.

Comment: App architecture is somewhat subjective but it sounds like your app is a great fit for Ember (what app isn't these days!). Though, trying to run multiple apps is really overcomplicating things and it's not really beneficial. It'll probably make your code less DRY and harder to maintain (think about the application template, for example). There are many large, complex Ember apps out there. Only thing I would add is if you're using a RESTful API and you have a million things happening on one page, your app probably isn't designed to be restful and might need some refactoring.

Comment: " what app isn't these days" sounds like lousy ads  to me