# ember-cli: split application into separate directories

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, broccolijs

My ember application has a few distinct components. There is a lot of code, so I want the sources organized into separate directories.

Let's say I have this directory structure:

```
[app]
  - [controllers]
  - [models]
  - [routes]
  - [views]
[dashboard]
  - [controllers]
  - [models]
  - [routes]
  - [views]
[admin]
  - [controllers]
  - [models]
  - [routes]
  - [views]
```

I want these directories all merged into `app` at build-time. I don't need to support conflicting names, e.g. `app/controllers/foo.js` + `dashboard/controllers/foo.js`.

My goal is a basic level of organization. I don't want to prefix `/dashboard/` all over the app, and I don't want to slow down the build.

Similar to this question: [Multiple "apps" with ember-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661924/multiple-apps-with-ember-cli) which I understand the ember-cli folks are working on and that it's not ready yet.

Any other ideas on how to organize the app are more than welcome.

---

I tried this, but the files in `dashboard` are being ignored.

```
// Brocfile.js
var mergeTrees = require('broccoli-merge-trees');

var app = new EmberApp();
var dashboard = new EmberApp({
    trees: {
        app: 'dashboard'
    }
});

module.exports = mergeTrees([ dashboard.toTree(), app.toTree() ], { overwrite: true });
```

Comment: Do you try to use addons for dashboard and admin? I used addon to separate some models and the only disadvantage is that livereload doesn't work on addon changing.

Comment: I haven't tried addons. I definitely want live reloading to work.

Comment: I created an addon using the `in-repo-addon` blueprint. File watching and live reloading does seem to work. This looks promising!